# How can I make my if condition more simple?

Tags: php, if-statement

I was trying to find a shorter way to write this if condition:

```
if($template == "documents"){
  $slug = $template;
  $parent = "products";
} else {
  $slug = $slug;
  $parent = $parent;
}
```

This is my approach:

```
$slug = ($template == "documents") ? $template : $slug;
$parent = ($template == "documents") ? "products" : $parent;
```

I have the feeling this code could be reduced more. But I do not know how.

Comment: Shorter doesn't mean simpler, in fact, the more "clever" you get, the more confusing your code can become. Why not leave cleverness to the compiler/interpreter?

Comment: note: if $slug = $slug and $parent = $parent in the else, then surely they're not even needed? Just needs one if without an else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second answer is minimal.  Your first answer is longer but more maintainable.  Some languages (Python and others) support multiple assignment, but not PHP or Perl.  In those languages, you could do:

```
(slug, parent) = (template == "documents") ?
  (template,  "products") : (slug, parent)
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to write that this is php

Comment: You mean, your suggested code does not work in php?

Comment: maybe like this?  `($slug, $parent) = ($template== "documents") ? ($template, "products") : ($slug, parent);`

Comment: php supports multi assignment for a long time: `php -r 'list($a,$b) = TRUE ? array(11,12) : array(21,22); printf("%s %s\n",$a,$b);'`. Replace `TRUE` by `FALSE` to see the difference.

Answer (score 5):

code of else condition seems useless as you are setting same variable again with same value. You can only use if condition:

```
if ($template == "documents") {
    $slug = $template;
    $parent = "products";
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: this to me, seems like the actual answer

Answer (score 1):

It can be evaluated too short like:

```
($template == "documents")?($slug = $template AND $parent = "products"): ($slug = $slug AND $parent = $parent)
```

Note: Suspecting you are using php

Answer (score 1):

Modification of answer by JoshGagliardi:

```
list($slug,$parent) = template == "documents" 
      ? array($template,"products") : array($slug,$parent);
```

Anyway, this is the best (reading) for me:

```
if ($template == "documents") {
    $slug   = $template;
    $parent = "products";
}
```